# Joining multiple tables and getting an error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to generate a report in SQL and I keep encountering an error.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW REPORT1 AS
SELECT c.ChannelNumber, s.SupplierName, p.PackageID, pro.ProgramName, r.RatingCode, sch.ShowTime
FROM Program pro
LEFT OUTTER JOIN Rating r
ON pro.RatingID = r.ratingID 
LEFT OUTTER JOIN Supplier s
ON pro.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
LEFT OUTTER JOIN Schedule sch
ON pro.ProgramID = sch.ProgramID
LEFT OUTTER JOIN Channel c
ON shc.ChannelID = c.ChannelID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ChannelPackage cp
ON ch.ChannelID = cp.ChannelID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Package p
ON cp.PackageID = p.PackageID
WHERE  sch.ShowTime  = '14-OCT-13'
ORDER BY ch.ChannelNumber, p.ProgramName;
```

I keep getting an error in line 4 that states "ORA-00905: missing keyword"  I have been trying for over an hour and cant figure out what I am doing wrong.  Any ideas?

*** UPDATE EDIT ***

Thanks guys!

Here is my updated code:

```
    CREATE VIEW REPORT1 AS
SELECT c.ChannelNumber, s.SupplierName, p.PackageID, pro.ProgramName, r.RatingCode, sch.ShowTime
FROM Program pro
    LEFT JOIN Rating r  ON pro.RatingID = r.ratingID 
    LEFT JOIN Supplier s ON pro.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
    LEFT JOIN Schedule sch ON pro.ProgramID = sch.ProgramID
    LEFT JOIN Channel c ON sch.ChannelID = c.ChannelID
    LEFT JOIN ChannelPackage cp ON c.ChannelID = cp.ChannelID
    LEFT JOIN  Packages p ON cp.PackageID = p.PackageID
WHERE  sch.ShowTime  =  &ShowTime
ORDER BY c.ChannelNumber, pro.ProgramName;
```

The report works now but it still does not display the channel numbers correctly but I think that is due to an error in how I configured the tables in the start.

Comment: Er, what type is `sch.ShowTime`?  Is it really a string formatted like that?  Note that if it's an actual date/time type, please use ISO formatting to make you queries more portable (as often, the formats used in queries depend on the locale settings of the servers; however, ISO is usually universally understood...)

Answer (score 2):

You spelled "Outer" wrong on the first 4 joins.  Since your first join is on line 4, that's where the DB is listing the compile error

Comment: OMG... thats what I get for looking at this screen for 9+ hours today!  Thanks I will fix my spelling and try again. *derp face*

Comment: @Michael Usually I find my mind getting sharper after the 10th hour.       Stay thirsty my friend

Answer (score 0):

Outer is unnecessary. Just use LEFT JOIN. 
Also its "outer" not "outter".